# Which mod changes the bucket recepie?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Apparently in the new Feed the Beast Unhinged mod pack buckets require steel plates and a hammer. Which mod implements this change? This sounds like the kind of thing GregTech would do but I have been unable to confirm if that mod is in fact the culprit.

Comment: Let us solve it with logical reasoning. First find the mods that have steel plates and then find mods that have a hammer. Cross reference, and voila!

Comment: @jeffreylin Mods can use/change stuff from other mods. GregTech is (in)famous for doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GregTech did in fact do it. It's hard to find documentation where this is stated officially but I've been roaming the FTB Forums and have confirmed that GregTech changed **a lot** of stuff after 1.4.7.